# When using crispy_forms, what controls the form name parameter?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

Looking at the [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#fundamentals), I see that the proper way to render a crispy form is simply

```
{% crispy form %}
```

However, [later on the page](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#rendering-several-forms-with-helpers) it suggests that the user can render multiple forms using

```
{% crispy form_1 %}
{% crispy form_2 %}
```

Where do I define `form_1` and `form_2`? (The form? The view?) I don't see those anywhere in the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

These names are the template context variables which are passed in the view to the `render()` function:

```
return render(request, 'my_form.html', {'form': form})

return render(request, 'my_form.html', {'form': my_form})

return render(request, 'my_form.html', {'form_1': form1, 'form_2': form2})

return render(request, 'my_form.html', {'form_1': first_form,
                                        'form_2': second_form})
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. I was using the `CreateForm` class, which was hiding that from me and confusing the hell out of me. So if I want to use more than one form, I would just use [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) to add the other forms?

Comment: Did you mean `CreateView`? Yes, you can inject into context data as many forms as you want.  But `CreateView` will validate only the one form, so you have to instantiate/validate/save other forms manually. In this case I suggest to write standard function-based view instead of using the `CreateView`.

Comment: BTW, yesterday I answered a question with the code that may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28459289/548165