# Django form to create several objects with one-to-one relation

Tags: python, django

I have several models with one-to-one relation. For example

```
class Task(models.Model):
     initial_comment = models.OneToOneField('Comment')
     # A pack of other fields

class Comment(models.Model)
    body = RichTextField()
    # A pack of other fields
```

I want to create "create view" based on form, that gives user ability to create task and initial comment there.

- I can't use `CreateView` because it is based on only one model
- I can't use `ModelForm` because it is based on only one model
- I can create several forms, but I can't join them into one formset (forms are different)
- I feel "`inlineformset_factory`" (`InlineFormSet`) should be used here, but I am not sure it suits best. Is there any 3rd party Django app to do that?

Sure I can create form myself, but I do not want to copy/paste all fields, their types, localized labels, validations and so on. I just want to list their names (like `fields` attibute).

I can also have 2 forms and support them everywhere and track dependencies manually (save comments first), like in [How can create a model form in django with a one-to-one relation with another model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458770/how-can-create-a-model-form-in-django-with-a-one-to-one-relation-with-another-mo) , but I hope there has to be better solution.

If you wonder why do I need one-to-one: Comments are used heavily in other places and have different relations with different models.

Answer (score 0):

The inline_formset factory is correct. There are no standard generic views for this, but there is a third party package with generic views to do what you are wanting. Its in the standard Django way of doing things.

https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views

You probably want to use the CreateWithInlinesView for that.

Comment: Thank you, but this view requires Comment (in my example) to have Foreign Key to Task which is not my case. Foreign keys are also supported by inline formsets in Django, but not one-to-one relations..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found solution.

`CreateWithInlinesView` works perfectly with `OneToOneField` (after all, 1-to-1 is just a foreign key with constraint), but my main model here is `Comment`, not `Task`. So I should set `Comment` as `model` field in this view and `Task` as `inline`. It looks silly. I will create custom form or review my model structure.